# How to create and upload a video to parse server?

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am able to upload image file to S3 using parse server. (by creating parse file from base64 image data and doing save() on parse file)

How can I do the same thing for a video file? I am doing this using parse-server js library in Ionic 2 app with typescript. The below code worked for images.

```
let file = new Parse.File("thumbnail", { base64: imageData });
        file.save().then(() => {
            // The file has been saved to Parse.
            console.log("File uploaded....");
        }, (error) => {
            // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
            console.log("File upload failed.");
        });
```

In case of a video file, I have the file location received from cordova media capture callback. Help me in uploading the video file.

Thank you

Comment: How did you solve it in the end? I am trying to do new Parse.File("name", {base64: data}) but its throwing error at the same line.

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution after days of research.
it works for iphone.
the important statement is this:
data=data.replace("quicktime","mov");

```
var options = { limit: 1, duration: 30 };
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(files){
    // Success! Audio data is here
    console.log("video file ready");
    var vFile = files[0];
    console.log(vFile.fullPath);
    ///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A0069EB-F864-438F-A685-A0DAE97F8B2D/tmp/capture-T0x144510b50.tmp.GfXOow/capturedvideo.MOV
    self.auctionvideo = vFile.fullPath; //localURL;
    console.log(self.auctionvideo);

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var file;
    fileReader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
        var data = fileReader.result;
        data=data.replace("quicktime","mov");
        console.log(data);
        //data:video/quicktime;base64,AAAAFGZ0
        console.log(data.length);
        self.auctionvideo=data;
        self.videofile = {base64:data};
    };
    //fileReader.reasAsDataURL(audioFile); //This will result in your problem.
    file = new window.File(vFile.name, vFile.localURL, 
                           vFile.type, vFile.lastModifiedDate, vFile.size);
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file); //This will result in the solution.
    // fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file); //This will result in the solution.
},
function(error){

},
options);
```